# how to change textColor of past and future dates in react-native-date-picker

Tags: react-native, react-native-datetimepicker

i have [android version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3VkN.png)
[ios version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoJzv.png)

i need current time to be white, and past and future time to be red, how to customize it?
if i set textColor={'red'}, it change color for every time

```
 <DatePicker
   androidVariant="nativeAndroid"
   textColor={'red'}
   fadeToColor="blue"
   open={isOpen}
   date={date}
   mode="datetime"
   minimumDate={currentDate}
   onConfirm={newDate => handleDateChange(newDate)}
   onCancel={handleCloseModal}
   onDateChange={newDate => handleDateChange(newDate)}
/>
```

how to change the text color?